# get user info via google api client

Tags: php, laravel, google-oauth, google-api-client, laravel-socialite

I'm recieving `token-id` from android client.
In the first step I'm validating the token via following code:

```
            $tokenId = $request->get('token-id');
            $google_client = new Google_Client();
            $google_client->setApplicationName("Ashojash");
            $google_client->setClientId(env("GOOGLE_KEY"));
            $google_client->setClientSecret(env("GOOGLE_SECRET"));
            $google_client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
            $google_client->addScope(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login']);
            $credentials = $google_client->verifyIdToken($tokenId);
            if ($credentials)
            {
                $data = $credentials->getAttributes();
                // validate aud against server client_id

                return $data['payload']['sub']; // user ID
            }
               return false;
```

received data from Google is:

```
 array:2 [
"envelope" => array:2 [
"alg" => "RS256"
"kid" => "23e5872762976b37944c33e4b2602656093ece91"
 ]
"payload" => array:12 [
"iss" => "https://accounts.google.com"
"aud" => "346904023124-73h70s03c0dipla8ltcbcd2ko076ft43.apps.googleusercontent.com"
"sub" => "111167217866315036918"
"email_verified" => true
"azp" => "346904023124-lehbs8510nibuq5ci125h8mu6u2ir4q1.apps.googleusercontent.com"
"email" => "jhon.f.kenedy777@gmail.com"
"iat" => 1452178925
"exp" => 1452182525
"name" => "john F.kenedy"
"given_name" => "john"
"family_name" => "F.kenedy"
"locale" => "en"]
    ]
```

After I've validated token-id, How do I get user info?
What I'm interested in are:
1-Email
2-User basic information
3-Google plus info
I've installed Socialite too, so if possible include your answers with Socialite too.

Comment: isn't your data from google is the user info?  i see a name, email, etc.

Comment: @sstarlight if you mean the second block of my code, that is retrieved from google via ``id-token``

Comment: I think $data['payload']['email'] contains the user's email and so on..

Answer (score 2):

Using [google-api-php-client library](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-verifytoken-php), once you get the result from $google_client->verifyIdToken you can access all the attributes you already posted in your question.

Tested with:

```
define('ROOT_PATH', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
require_once (ROOT_PATH.'/google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php');


$ClientID_debug = 'xxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$ClientID_release = 'xxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$mToken = $_POST['mToken'];
$build = $_POST['build'];

$google_client = new Google_Client();

if($build=='DEBUG'){
   $google_client->setClientId($ClientID_debug);
}else{
   $google_client->setClientId($ClientID_release);
}

$google_result = $google_client->verifyIdToken($mToken);


if ($google_result){
  $data = $google_result->getAttributes();
  $tokenUserID = $data['payload']['sub'];
  $tokenAudience = $data['payload']['aud'];
  $tokenEmail = $data['payload']['email'];
  //etc..

  //send result back to Android client (could also use JSON to send all attributes)
  echo($tokenAudience);
}
```

Call from Android using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    try {
        //Always use https to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks!
        URL url = new URL("https://www.example.com/validateTokenID.php");
        Map<String, Object> HTTPpostParams = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            //debug build
            HTTPpostParams.put("build", "DEBUG");
        }else{
            //release build
            HTTPpostParams.put("build", "RELEASE");
        }

        HTTPpostParams.put("mToken", MygoogleSignedInAccount.getIdToken());

        StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> param : HTTPpostParams.entrySet()) {
            if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            postData.append('=');
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
        }
        byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);

        Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder strB = new StringBuilder();

        for ( int c = in.read(); c != -1; c = in.read() ) strB.append((char) c);

        return strB.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //this.exception = e;
        Log.e("MyApp", e.getMessage());
        return e.getMessage();
    }

}
```

Comment: this has changed in v2 :
$userData = $client->verifyIdToken($idToken);
$userId = $userData['sub'];